# No se aplican las fórmulas en phpspreadsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

Mi problema reside a la hora de aplicar una fórmula a una celda de Excel.

Aplico el valor de la siguiente manera:

```
$formula = '=((E' . $row. '*G' . $row. ')+G' . $row. ')*F' . $row;
$sheet->getCell('D' . $row)->setValue($formula);
```

El problema es que el valor de la celda sí es el de la fórmula, pero esta no se aplica, el valor siempre es 0.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El valor de la fórmula para la linea 7 es el siguiente: `=((E7*G7)+G7)*F7`

El valor de la columna E es un número decimal, pero aplicado estilo de porcentaje.

Cuando pulso soble la celda para editar la fórmula y me salgo, automáticamente se calcula y se pone bien el valor, es decir que la fórmula es correcta pero el excel no la interpreta.

Cuando guardo el documento automáticamente se calculan todas las fórmulas.

He probado `$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas();`, pero sin éxito.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Yo siempre lo hice de la siguiente manera `$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("D".$row, $formula)`. A lo mejor de esa manera sí te funciona

Comment: @MatíasRodríguez tampoco funciona

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo he conseguido de la siguiente manera:

```
Settings::setLocale('en');
```

Y luego las **fórmulas en inglés**, por ejemplo, en vez de:

```
=SUMA(A1:A5)
```

poner

```
=SUM(A1:A5)
```

porque luego tu Excel reconoce tu locale y la traduce. A mí me funciona, ¡espero que sirva!

**UPDATE:**

Además, que después de tantas pruebas ya ni me acordaba que lo había puesto, hay que añadir el valor así:

```
$sheet->getCell('A6')->setValueExplicit('=SUM(A1:A5)', DataType::TYPE_FORMULA);
```

Y también:

```
$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(true);
```

Así que no estabas muy lejos, pero había más cosas, por lo menos a mí me ha funcionado.